# Как в nodejs приложении запустить исполняемый файл?

Tags: node.js, npm, binary

Имеется файл, с таким содержимым

```
const hello = 'Hello!'
console.log(hello)
```

Я его упаковал с помощью этого упаковщика [npm pkg](https://github.com/webkostya/pkg)

На выходе получается исполняемый файл. Если его запустить в терминале, то все работает, терминал выводит `Hello!`
Собственно сам вопрос, как его выполнить в nodejs приложении ?

Например в NW JS можно упаковать файл таким образом

`nwjc source.js binary.bin`

и потом выполнить

```
nw.Window.get().evalNWBin(frame, 'binary.bin')
```

Может кто знает как еще можно закрыть исходный код ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const { exec } = require('pkg');
```

`exec(args)` принимает массив аргументов командной строки и возвращает промис. Например:

```
 await exec ( [ ' app.js ' , ' --target ' , ' host ' , ' --output ' , ' app.exe ' ] );
// что-то делать с app.exe, запускать, тестировать, загружать, развертывать и т. д.
```

Так же можно попробовать [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('тут команда терминала', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: Так и сделал ) Жаль только `pkg` делает большой размер